# Parallax content area using primary scroll bar

Tags: html, css

Looking at trying to set the page up where the html is `overflow: hidden` and the header and footer are fixed and the body content is `overflow: scroll`.

The current issue is, the scrollbar appears within the content div. Is it possible to set the "primary" browser scrollbar to interact with the content div only?

Revalent CSS:

```
html {
   overflow: hidden;
}
header {
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height: 15%;
}
footer {
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 10%;
   height: 5%;
}
#content {
   position: fixed;
   height: 80%;
   max-width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

Here is the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/6gcfx/ (keep in mind this is not the primary scrollbar that is moving the content, as desired).

Comment: You say you have `body{overflow:scroll}`, but I don't see it (there are two `html{overflow:hidden}`s by the way). It's unclear as to what you're asking

Comment: Sorry, copied html again instead of header properties. Essentially, I would like the content to be the only element of the screen that scrolls. The header, and footer will remain fixed.

Comment: Created a JS fiddle to show concept: http://jsfiddle.net/6gcfx/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using percent height (as in your question) you can do it this way, using `position:fixed` on the header and footer and `position:absolute` on the body

```
html { overflow: hidden; }
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height:15%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}
#content {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 70%;
}
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0%;
    height:15%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

[image: jsFiddle]

If the heights of the header and footer are not in percents, you can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) instead. This approach, however, [generally requires more modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/calc), thus you'd have to have a javascript fallback if you're wishing to support older browsers

```
html { overflow: hidden; }
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height:75px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    top:75px; /* Height of header */
    overflow: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 125px); /* 100% - (headerHeight + footerHeight) */
}
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0%;
    height:50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Answer (score -1):

Pardon my newness, but I think I see your problem.
Switch your content div to

```
#content {
position:float;
top:(header size);
```

And switch the header and footer to

```
position:fixed;
```

So the content should scroll with the page scroll bar and the header/footer be unmoved.

Comment: I think you understand the issue, unfortunately there is no `position: float;` property. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: I use it all the time, but use float:center then? If that doesn't work, put your main content in a float:left/right inside an empty position:absolute placeholder.

Comment: @SusuReedJango There is no `float:center` either